# phonegap Media Error code 0

Tags: android, cordova

first time when i play a mp3 file using phonegap media it works fine. but wen i stop and again play for 2nd time it does not and 3rd time when i play it shows error code 0

below is code

```
           var my_media = null;
            var mediaTimer = null;
            var pausePos = 0;
            var counter=0;
            var playing=false;




          function playAudio(src) {
         // Create Media object from src
             if(my_media==null){
               my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            }


 if(!playing){
// get audio duration
var duration =  my_media.getDuration();


// set slider data
if( duration > 0 ){
    $('#slider').attr( 'max', Math.round(duration) );
    $('#slider').slider('refresh');
}

 // Play audio
my_media.play();
playing=true;
$("#play_pause_img").attr("src","img/pause.png")


// Update my_media position every second
if (mediaTimer == null) {
    mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
        // get my_media position
        my_media.getCurrentPosition(
            // success callback
            function(position) {
                if (position > -1) {
                    setAudioPosition(position);
                }
            },
            // error callback
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
            }
        );
    }, 1000);
}
}
else{
     pauseAudio();
     playing=false;
     $("#play_pause_img").attr("src","img/play.png");
}

}



     function pauseAudio() {
         if (my_media) {
             my_media.pause();
         }
         }

         function resumeAudio()
           {
             my_media.play();
           }



        function stopAudio() {
             if (my_media) {
               my_media.stop();
                my_media.release();
              playing=false;
              $("#play_pause_img").attr("src","img/play.png");
               }
              clearInterval(mediaTimer);
              mediaTimer = null;
              pausePos = 0;
              $('#slider').val(pausePos);
              $('#slider').slider('refresh');
              }



       function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
         }


         function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
             }
```

what could be the reason and what is error code 0.

Answer (score 2):

In `3.5.0` I'm experiencing the error function firing with an error code of `0`.

From older docs, `0` appears to mean `none`, and appears to be no indication of a problem.

I seems under these circumstances this can be ignored, and is not really an error

Answer (score 2):

it has to do with audio-ressources which are finite and therefore must get released. This is explained there: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

In my case it did the trick to call release() for my media object at that moment I don't use it anymore - I do it directly after calling stop()

```
    this.stopAudio = function() {
    if (my_media) {
        my_media.stop();
        my_media.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's indeed the issue, this is taken from the docs: `Releases the underlying operating system's audio resources. This is particularly important for Android, since there are a finite amount of OpenCore instances for media playback. Applications should call the release function for any Media resource that is no longer needed.`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I'm searching for the solution, but I didn't find anything.

My code:

```
$('#button').click(function{
   media = new Media('/android_asset/www/sonidos/trans/sound.m4a', play, error);                    
});
function play(){
    media.play();
}
function error(err){
    alert(err.code);
}
```

If i do in that way, the sound does not play and I get always the alert with 0. That not match with any error code from mediaError.

Testing and testing I make code works with next code:

```
    $('#button').click(function{
       media = new Media('/android_asset/www/sonidos/trans/sound.m4a', play, error);
       media.play();                    
    });
    function play(){
        ;
    }
    function error(err){
        ;
    }
```

I know is not the correct way but I can't find other solution.

P.D. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Add the release method in the onSuccess method in addition to the stop method you created.

```
function onSuccess() {
 my_media.release();
 console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
}
```